# Object oriented design question

Tags: c#, oop

I need to create a class which is building up an XML config file based on another objects.

There are 3 various objects. The building  algorithm is very similar for all objects,but not same.

I was thinking of using a base class with an abstract method and then just create a derived classes with where I'd override the abstract method.

But the problem is those 3 object doesn't have a common interface or base class. Those objects are third party components. I can't refactor them. So there isn't any common contract for all objects.

Is there any convenient solution for this situation ? Maybe some design pattern I don't know about ?

Comment: Are the types supported in your code likely to change? That is to ask, ought the solution be easily scalable to support further third party types? If not then simply use a base class to carry out common work and and derived classes to handle any specifics.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a `XMLSerializable` abstract class and then use the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to adapt these third party components into `XMLSerializable` objects

Answer (score 1):

you can create your 3 custom class extending them respectively [I am not sure about C#], and implement a common contract.

Answer (score 1):

[Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) seems to fit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you could also use a datatable class. These can read and write xml files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx